# Formatting JSON to html in wordpress using php

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api, plugins

I have an api that returns this

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "medicineId": 15,
        "medicineName": " Alectinib",
        "medicineDescription": "Alectinib is a second generation oral drug that selectively inhibits the activity of anaplastic lymphoma kinase (ALK) tyrosine kinase. It is specifically used in the treatment of non-small cell lung cancer (NSCLC) expressing the ALK-EML4 (echinoderm microtubule-associated protein-like 4) fusion protein that causes proliferation of NSCLC cells. Inhibition of ALK prevents phosphorylation and subsequent downstream activation of STAT3 and AKT resulting in reduced tumour cell viability.\r\n\r\nApproved under accelerated approval in 2015, alectinib is indicated for use in patients who have progressed on or were not tolerant of crizotinib, which is associated with the development of resistance.",
        "sideEffects": "tiredness . \r\nconstipation . \r\nswelling in your hands,feet,ankles,face .\r\nmuscle pain , tenderness and weakness (myalgia) .\r\nlow red blood cell count (anemia) .",
        "chemicalFormula": "\r\nC30H34N4O2",
        "indication": "Alectinib is a kinase inhibitor indicated for the treatment of patients with anaplastic lymphoma kinase (ALK)-positive, metastatic non-small cell lung cancer (NSCLC) who have progressed on or are intolerant to crizotinib. This indication is approved under accelerated approval based on tumor response rate and duration of response. Continued approval for this indication may be contingent upon verification and description of clinical benefit in confirmatory trials.",
        "associatedCondition": "Refractory, metastatic Non small cell lung cancer",
        "alternatives": [
            {
                "medicineId": 10,
                "medicineName": "Alclometasone"
            }
        ],
        "categories": [
            "BCRP/ABCG2 Inhibitors",
            "Antineoplastic and Immunomodulating Agents",
            " Antineoplastic Agents"
        ]
    },
    "message": "Successfully retrieved"
}
```

I want to format that to look good in a popup
Any idea how i can do that?

Comment: use json_decode()

Comment: Yes and after that, how i make each field has the value returned by the json

Comment: did u tried the solutions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you were looking for:

```
<?php
$contents = 'Your json result here';
$jsonArray = json_decode($contents,true);
$medicineId = $jsonArray["medicineId"];
?>

<h1> MedicineId: <?php echo $medicineId ?> </h1>
```